# How to specify the source dir for debian packaging "debian/rules"

Tags: debian, packaging

I'm using the generated folder structure that `dh_make` generates.
Everything is good as long as I mantain this structure:

```
./debian/
./debian/rules
./debian/<rest_of_files>
./Makefile
```

When I execute `fakeroot debian/rules clean binary` it does `make clean && make && make install DESTDIR=properplace` and everything works as my `Makefile` has those targets.

Now I wanted to move `debian/rules` to `packaging/debian/rules` but nothing works.
I try `fakeroot packaging/debian/rules clean binary` but that apparently looks for `Makefile` in `./packaging/` and not in `$CWD`

**EDIT:**
As others stated the build scripts don't like this, as a workaround I do this from the main makefile

```
package-debian:
ln -s packaging/debian debian
fakeroot debian/rules clean binary
rm debian
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that.  It's not supported.  The `debian` directory must be under the top level.

Even if you get it to work otherwise, which I doubt, everyone will hate you because it would break every tool in the world. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the Debian scripts inside your directory `packaging`.  That's just the way it is.